# Updating parent object of Account - via apex, process builder, workflow or formula

Tags: apex, workflow, formula, process-builder

We have object called `Account_Code__c`, which the `Account` object has lookup relationship to. In other words, a single `Account_Code__c` record may have multiple child `Account` records.

When an `Account` is created or edited with a certain `Type`, I need to update few fields in the `Account_Code__c` record with values from current `Account`.

I tried with formula, process builder and workflow, none of them would help me achieve this functionality.  I guess only option I have is trigger on `Account`.

Am I missing anything in workflow, process builder or in formula ?

**More Business process**

`Account Code` represents a family of all related `Account` records. Let's say all TechnoMajor company global HQ, Country HQ, Subsidiary or any other acquired companies are represented by one account code TEM.

Currently `Account Code` just has a `Serial Number` and `Account Code` fields. we wanted to add one new field `Global HQ Account Name`.

`Account Code` object record must look like below.

```
**Serial number**  **Account code**    **Global-HQ Name**  
00001               TEM                 Techno Major Inc.
```

`Account Code` is created first in and all related `Account` records are added later as part of business process.

When business person  adds an account with type 'Global HQ' corresponding account name must be populated in `Account Code` object.

Comment: ProcessBuilder should work assuming that when a DML on Account, the lookup relationship is populated. That said, if one Account_Code has many Accounts, the most recent DML event on a child Account will smash the values updated on Account_Code by the next most recent DML event on a child Account.  If this is your business model, great.  If not, you need to rethink your process.

Comment: You say you have a __one__ `Account_Code__c` to __many__ `Accounts` relationship.

That being the case, how and where did you imagine to store the __many__ values related to your `Accounts` in that one `Account_Code__c` record? Shouldn't you rather use additional custom fields for `Account` records and display them in that related list?

However, to understand what you are actually trying to achieve, please provide some details about the nature of your `Account_Code__c` object and the kind of "umbrella-function" it serves.

Comment: @crop1645, additional comment added..

Comment: @tobibeer, additional comment added

Comment: Ah, so only one Account in the family will have type='Global HQ' - then Process Builder on `Account` should be able to create the related `Account_Code__c` object. Why don't you post your process builder screen shots and identify where you are stuck

Comment: Can you show the process builder you have created, I want to see the criteria you added, with the immediate action.

Comment: @crop1645, thanks for the response.. Now business rules are changed, i have to go with apex.